# Moodle 3.4.1 - Server migration issues (require.js, jquery etc)

Tags: php, migration, moodle

Good morning everyone,
I have a backup of the folders Moodle and Moodledata (84gb) that I transferred from one server to another (always Linux, same domain and same features).
After copying all the files and setting the correct permissions to the folders, importing the DB and changing the paths in the config.php file, I see the site correctly with the chosen theme, but:

1. Some images are not visible (logo in the header and some images in the courses)
2. I have an error in console "No define call function in Require.js" in loading jQuery.
3. When opening a SCORM course, the player remains loading without the video starting (probably caused by point 2)

What am i doing wrong?
I tried to delete the Muc, cache, lock, trashdir folders as indicated in other threads but with the same result. What else could I check?
Thanks,
Dave

I tried to delete the Muc, cache, lock, trashdir folders as indicated in other threads but with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a checklist here for migrating Moodle to another server

https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Moodle_migration

I'm guessing you need to run the replace tool - this will replace the old urls with the new urls in the database

```
/admin/tool/replace/index.php
```